# Using Jolt, How do I remove a field "last_update" from everywhere in a JSON string?

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON array of objects and in many of the objects, at various points, there's a "last_update" field. ("Person" object may have a "Jobs" array and each Job in Jobs array may have an last_update, as well as the parent Person, as well as each Address in the "Addresses" object, etc.  The "last_updated" field is not always at the same depth for various objects and in some objects may appear in multiple places.

I want to remove any mention of "last_update" no matter where in the JSON tree it lands.

If I was editing the JSON in Vim, I'd probably try using something like `s/last_updated.*?//g`.

Comment: Since we're using GSON for other JSON needs, we ended up addressing it with some recursive, brute-force, find-n-forget call methods.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have OOTB support for that.